# Como reallizar um post em uma url https ignorando o certificado ssl ou passando os parâmetros para validar o certificado?

Tags: python, post, http-request, request, https

Meu código (gerado pelo postman), via postman funciona normalmente, via PowerShell também.

```
import requests
url = "https://tamcmdb.tivit.com/mctwpsapi/v1/api/new?"
payload={}
files={}
headers = {}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
print(response.text)
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, atualmente o código abaixo funciona quando o POST é feito em um ambiente dev, onde a API tem o endereço http://localhost/xpto, porém, quando usado em produção, onde o endereço é https, sempre eu retorna o erro abaixo:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tamcmdb.tivit.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /mctwpsapi/v1/api/new (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)')))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "D:\DEV\Python\MCT\BBL.py", line 6, in <module> (Current frame)
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

Tentei o comando `verify=False` para ignorar, Tentei com o comando, mas não funciona, gera o erro abaixo:

```
('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "D:\DEV\Python\MCT\BBL.py", line 6, in <module> (Current frame)
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files, verify=False)
```

Socorro

Comment: Pelo erro, o problema não é com o `verify=False` e sim porque o arquivo que você está enviando na requisição não existe: `FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')`.

Comment: Valeu Renan, no caso eu nem estou enviando um arquivo, mas de qualquer forma, vi que o BO estava no proxy da empresa ¬¬
Contornei a situação aqui pedindo exceção ao time, e deu tudo certo.